# Volley library and publish on Play Store

Tags: creative-commons, cc-by, publishing

I am using the Volley library, provided by Google, to do some http requests on android app. The Volley library is under the "Creative Commons Attribution 2.5".

If I want to publish my app later on the Play Store, do i have something special to do to be able to use this library ? I read the license but i don't really understand if there is some restrictions/things to do to use it.

Comment: The Creative Commons folks have extensive explanations on their licenses.

Comment: Where do you see that it is under "Creative Commons Attribution 2.5"? It looks like it's under Apache License 2.0 (which makes much more sense for software).

Answer (score 1):

Volley's license is the [Apache 2.0](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/Request.java) like most of the Android codebase.
So what you have to do is to comply with the Apache license. [Section 4](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0#redistribution) is quite an easy read and I did cut short some points in the excerpt:

```
4. Redistribution. You may reproduce and distribute copies of the Work or 
Derivative Works thereof in any medium, with or without modifications, and 
in Source or Object form, provided that You meet the following conditions:

   a) You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a 
      copy of this License; and
   b) You must cause any modified files to carry prominent notices stating 
      that You changed the files; and
   c) You must retain, in the Source form of any Derivative Works that You 
      distribute, all copyright, patent, trademark, and attribution notices
      from the Source form of the Work, excluding those notices that do not
      pertain to any part of the Derivative Works; and
   d) If the Work includes a "NOTICE" text file as part of its distribution,
      then any Derivative Works that You distribute must include a readable
      copy of the attribution notices contained within such NOTICE file [...]

    You may add Your own copyright statement to Your modifications and may
    provide additional or different license terms and conditions for use,
    reproduction, [....]
```